# 'cannot change type of fields: "publicKey", delete the fields and re-create them' Polybase Error

Tags: polybase

I am trying to change the value of some fields in my Polybase App but when I click save the error pops up and doesn't allow me to change anything.

I Googled for the solution but neither Google nor their docs show me how to alter a field value. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.